# formatting time (using timespec) to get the right value in nano seconds

Tags: c++, time, number-formatting

I wish to format ns and ns_old, so that I verify if obeys the inter_arrival that is set (ie, if i give inter_arrival =10, it should rightly reflect in ns_diff). Could someone give some details on how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>      // for getting time 
#include <sys/time.h> // for time 
#include <unistd.h> // for microsecond sleep
#include <stdint.h> // for different integer types
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t ns, sec, ns_old, ns_diff;
struct timespec ts;
int inter_arrival = 10;

void ttime_func(){
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
ns = ts.tv_sec * 1000000000 + ts.tv_nsec;
ns_diff = ns -ns_old;

// writing to my output log file
std::cout << ns_old << "\t" << ns << "\t" << ns_diff << "\t" << std::endl;
ns_old = ns;
usleep(inter_arrival);
}

int main()
{

for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
{
ttime_func();
}

}
```

Comment: where are the declaration and initialization of ns_old?

Comment: sorry i have a large codebase. so simplified it

Comment: Unfortunately, you "simplified" it by removing the thing you're asking about. Please post your [_minimal testcase_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does inter_arrival =10 mean you want to ensure a gap of at least/exactly/at most 10 nanoseconds inbetween each call of your start_pkt_gen function ? (Note that this will be impossible, as a kernel can't provide that kind of scheduling guarantees even if you used nanosleep() instead of usleep(), also your logging statements will take more than 10 nanoseconds, and usleep() sleeps for microseconds which is 3 orders of magnitude greater than nanoseconds)

Comment: I have now given a working version of my code. I just want to verify if the the time interval we sleep in microseconds is executed right. I may not need nano second precision now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per any sleep function, they don't sleep as exactly as we mention. It 'tries' to sleep as we mention. The wake up time is different from time to time. Specially, the time interval is too short the accuracy of sleep interval degrades.

Comment: Thanks Sargi, I am ok with microsecond precision for my application. So even then is the wake up time different?

Comment: @user2532296 Yes. Even with microseconds level sleeps wake up times are different. No timer in the earth fired in such accuracy.